# find most common consecutive two word sequence awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file named 'file'.
I need to find most common two word sequence using awk, while "this is" and "is this" are considered equal in our count.

sample text :
name my name is this is our text is this

expected output : 
is this 3

I used this loop :

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++) 
    a[$i OFS $(i+1)]++
    }' file
```

anyone has any idea why it fails?

Comment: Add sample text and the expected output to your question.

Comment: What do you expect if there are two combinations with the same frequency? Do you need to handle multi-line input? Please [edit] your question to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails due to never reading the file.  The special `BEGIN` block is executed *before* the first input file named on the command line is even opened for reading (and the `END` block after the last). You also don't have any output from the code.

Others have given their own solutions to the issue, so I'll take your code and modify it slightly:

1. Run the code in an ordinary block to have it execute for each line in the input.
2. Use an `END` block to find the most common combination of words in the array and do the output after all the input has been processed.
3. Make sure that the words in each pair is always used in lexicographical order.

```
awk '
    {
        for (i = 1; i < NF; i++)
            if ($i < $(i+1)) a[$i OFS $(i+1)]++
            else             a[$(i+1) OFS $i]++
    }
    END {
        for (words in a)
            if (a[words] > a[m]) m = words
        print m, a[m]
    }' file
```

With the given input, this would print `is this 3`.

An alternative implementation that keeps track of the maximum while reading the file, and then just prints it at the end:

```
awk '
    {
        for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) {
            if ($i < $(i+1)) words = $i OFS $(i+1)
            else             words = $(i+1) OFS $i
            if (++count[words] > count[m]) m = words
        }
    }
    END { print m, count[m] }' file
```

Without faffing about with arrays:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) if ($i < $(i+1)) print $i, $(i+1); else print $(i+1), $i }' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

That is, just use `awk` to generate the word combinations (one on each line), then sort these, get the number of times each occur, sort *these* (by the count), and pick out the one with the greatest count. Doing to `sort` calls would be expensive on huge data though, but running on small things like email messages etc., this would be enough.

Comment: thank you, I used your second code and it works!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
gawk '{
       for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
           delete arr; split($(i-1) "\n" $i, arr);
           asort(arr); s[arr[1] FS arr[2]]++
       };
     }
END { for(x in s) print s[x], x }' infile |sort -nr
3 is this
2 my name
1 our text
1 is text
1 is our
1 is name
```

`split()` function adds pair of strings (separated by whitespaces (tab/space)) into an array `arr` but each in separate lines `\n`.

`asort()` function sorts this `arr` array; then we add result into another array called `s` with key as pair of sorted strings and value increment for each same pair of strings if seen again.

`delete arr` deletes the array `arr` for the use of process for next pair of fields.

at the `END` we loop over array `s` elements and print count of each pairs seen and the pairs themselves; `sort -nr` sorts the result and give you most repeated pair of strings.

note: in result it won't tell you if there was most `is this` or `this is` or all just one of these, this will just tell you sorted result of all in `is this` as the result for this example.

Answer (score 0):

As @kusalananda pointed out your main mistake was puting all of your code in a BEGIN block. So that `"this is" and "is this" are considered equal in our count.` you need to do something like this to guarantee that every pair of words you come across are stored in a specific (sorted) order no matter which relative order they appear in the input:

```
awk '
{
    for(i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        pair = ($i > $(i+1) ? $i OFS $(i+1) : $(i+1) OFS $i)
        c = ++cnt[pair]
        max = (max > c ? max : c)
    }
}
END {
    for (pair in cnt) {
        c = cnt[pair]
        if ( c == max ) {
            print pair, c
        }
    }
}
' file
this is 3
```